# How to find all pointers referencing a certain address in the memory space using GDB?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, gdb

I want to find all pointers in my program referencing a certain address. How can I do this using GDB? Thanks. My program is in C++

Comment: Maybe someone will have some magic for you, but until then I'm going to say you can't. The big question is why do you need to? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Scan all of process memory for that value?  It will have false positives.

Comment: You can put a watchpoint on that address and find all places that actually dereference these pointers.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont this will not help much with source level debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "difficult topic". You are probably going to struggle to do this with gdb alone but valgrind may help (see http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.valgrind-monitor-commands for what valgrind can do when running as a gdbserver). In fact valgrind has a technique for doing tracking pointers to detect memory leaks... However if your program does something tricky with pointers (like masking them off then recreating them, packing them, keeping them non-aligned etc) no standard tool will be able to help you.